# Upper bound on the number of perfect matchings in $K_{3,3}$-free graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, perfect-matchings

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with an even number of vertices $|V|=2n$. Assume that $G$  is $K_{3,3}$-free i.e. it does not contain a graph isomorphic to [biclique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph)  $K_{3,3}$. A perfect matching of $G$ is a partition of the set of vertices $V$ onto disjoint two-element subsets according to edges $E$.

**Question:**
Are there any known *upper bounds* for the number of perfect matchings of such graphs?

I am not a specialist in graph theory and after an extensive internet search, I was only able to find that the complexity of computing perfect matchings for such $K_{3,3}$-free graphs is lower than the one in the general [case](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/6700/87-860.pdf;jsessionid=1677D94933036CEEAF479CFD9FD7F2EB?sequence=1) (it reduces to NC from beeing  #P hard).

**Motivation**: I stumbled on this problem while studying an unrelated physics problem that concerns contextuality in a restricted model of quantum computing based on Majorana fermions (see for example [this work](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0511178) by Bravyi).

Comment: Such a graph without a $K_{3,3}$ has at most $n^{2-1/3}$ edges. This combined with a result of Alon and Friedland (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2578.pdf) gives a non-trivial upper bound, but I do not know if it would be sharp.

Comment: Thanks. These bounds turned out to be good enough for our purposes! Applying them gives that the maximal number of perfect matching in $K_{3,3}$-free graphs is at most  $(n^{2/3}/2)^n$.